# PDF Creator Output Error

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I try to build with PDF Creator a dynamically PDF File but I get some Errors when I want to output it. Why I get errors when I try to output it?
If I delete $pdf->output(); then I get no error's but nothing shows of the PDF.

Error Message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\pdf_creator\fpdf.php:271 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\pdf_creator\fpdf.php(1063): FPDF->Error('Some data has a...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\pdf_creator\fpdf.php(999): FPDF->_checkoutput() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\pages\rechnung_pdf.php(44): FPDF->Output() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php(38): include('C:\xampp\htdocs\htdocs...') #4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\pdf_creator\fpdf.php on line 271

My Code: ( this is the whole file code how I tried it )

```
<?php
require_once("pdf_creator/fpdf.php");
$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','A4');
$pdf->AddPage(); 
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B', 16); 

# Kunden Daten
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','I', 13);
$pdf->Cell(0, 8, 'Herr', 0, 1, 'L');
$pdf->Cell(0, 8, utf8_decode('Max'), 0, 1, 'L');
$pdf->Cell(0, 8, utf8_decode('Mustermann'), 0, 1, 'L');

# Header Rechnung
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','I', 13);
$pdf->Cell(0, 10, utf8_decode('Rechnungsdatum: xx.xx.xxxx'), 0, 1, 'R');
$pdf->Cell(0, 10, utf8_decode('Liefer- bzw. Leistungsdatum: xx.xx.xxxx'), 0, 1, 'R');
$pdf->Cell(0, 10, utf8_decode('Steuernummer: xxx xxx xxx'), 0, 1, 'R');


# Rechnung Content
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B', 13);
$pdf->Cell(0, 20, utf8_decode('Rechnung Nr. xxxxxxxxxx'), 0, 1);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','I', 13);
$pdf->Cell(0, 20, utf8_decode('Wir bedanken uns für die gute Zusammenarbeit und stellen Ihnen'), 0, 1);
$pdf->Cell(0, 0, utf8_decode('vereinbarungsgemäß folgende Lieferungen und Leistungen in Rechnung:'), 0, 1);

$pdf->Cell(0, 20, '______________________________________________________________', 0, 1);
$pdf->Cell(0, -8, utf8_decode('Nummer                    Bezeichnung          Menge      Einzel/€      Gesammt/€'), 0, 1);
$pdf->Cell(0, 13, '______________________________________________________________', 0, 1);

$pdf->Cell(0, 60, '______________________________________________________________', 0, 1);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 13);
$pdf->Cell(0, -30, 'Rechnungsbetrag: xx Euro', 0, 1);

# Footer Nachricht
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','I', 13);
$pdf->Cell(0, 80, utf8_decode('Nach §19 Abs. 1 UStG wird keine Umsatzsteuer berechnet.'), 0, 1);
$pdf->Cell(0, -60, utf8_decode('Die Rechnung ist sofort fällig.'), 0, 1);
$pdf->Cell(0, 80, utf8_decode('Wir bedanken uns für Ihr Vertrauen!'), 0, 1);
$pdf->Cell(0, -60, utf8_decode('Für jegliche Rückfragen stehen wir Ihnen gerne zur Verfügung.'), 0, 1);
$pdf->output();
?>
```

I hope somebody can help me, I read a lot in the documentation but nothing helped me :/

Comment: That error means that data is already being sent to the buffer before you try to output the PDF. FPDF won't work if anything besides the PDF is being sent to the screen.

Comment: Do you have anything before the `<?php`?

Comment: chris85 no, it's just this PHP file, I posted the whole file content.

HenryA. hmmm, but what I don't understand, I nothing sent already to the buffer...

Answer (score 0):

Let's sort things.

1. The output() method of FPDF works only if there is absolutely no data sent to the browser before. No whitespace, no carriage return – simply nothing.
2. But, there *is* output before you call $pdf->output(). It's at least one error message. The FPDF class throws an exception (as the error message you posted says):

   "#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\pdf_creator\fpdf.php(1063): FPDF->Error('Some data has a...')"

My guess is the Euro sign. You convert the text data from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1. This is due to the behavior of uft8_decode. Unfortunately, the ISO-8859-1 charset does not contain a Euro sign encoding.

Try to use iconv with target encoding window-1252 instead of utf8_decode.

For debugging, try to replace your data with some ANSI-Text, remove transcoding at all and I promise it will work.

Best regards,
Andreas

Comment: okay i tried it out but it doesn't work.
When I only use: 

    require_once("pdf_creator/fpdf.php");
    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage(); 
    $pdf->output();

I get the same errors :/

Comment: Now I found my mistake!
I have a dynamically Website so each single PHP page I can reach it with: localhost/index.php?page=pdf_creator
Thats the problem if I open the site with: localhost/pdf_creator.php it works.
What the different is I don't know but now I try to get the site otherwise.

But thanks for your help guys!

Comment: Then /index.php seems to output something before processing the fpdf.php. Is it a CMS like Typo3, Wordpress or something like that?

Comment: I don't know what Typo3 is, I use for the main page to control the pages with:

        <?php         
            require_once("../config/verbindung.php");
            include("../config/function.php");
        
            if(isset($_GET["page"])) $page = $_GET["page"];
                else $page = "home";
            if(file_exists('pages/'.$page.'.php'))
       include('pages/'.$page.'.php');
            else include("pages/index.php");
        ?>

( sry for the formating here, i don't know how I have to use it here :3 )

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the index.php and all included files ("config.php" and so on) do NOT output anything, not even a whitespace or a carriage return. Please check the files for whitespaces / CRs before and after the "<?php" / "?>" markers and remove them.
Some editors will add a blank line at the end of the file when saving the file. Check this, too.

Hth, Andreas